# Apache serves with new and old SSL Root certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am hosting a website at https://www.tabletop.cloud

A while back I switched from the `DST Root CA X3` root certificate to the `ISRG Root X1` certificate. When I access my website in every browser the SSL certificate seems to be working as normal (see below images 1 & 2)

However, I have an iPad that is refusing to use the new certificate and for some reason is receiving a recently signed version of the `DST Root CA X3` certificate. (See below image 3, screenshot taken with TLS inspector app)

I've checked if the iPad accepts other websites with the `ISRG Root X1` certificate, and it does so without issue.

I've also tried deleting the certificates and letting acme.sh generate new ones from scratch. (However I did not delete the configuration files in `/root/.acme.sh/tabletop.cloud` because I was unsure if I could do so safely)

I am really confused because I did not think that it was possible to supply different SSL certs based on platform/browser(?).

I am using:

- Apache 2.4.41
- acme.sh for lets encrypt certificate requests

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: At first glance I see that you server only sends the signed server certificate and not the intermediate / chain certificate(s). That might be the reason stuff breaks. Consider using the `fullchain` version in stead of only the certificate in your Apache SSL config

Comment: Interesting, I noticed this on the SSL Labs test. I'll try that out thanks!

Comment: @Bob You're a hero this fixed the issue! If you add it as an answer I will accept it when I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for including your actual domain name. At first glance I see that you server only sends the signed server certificate and not the intermediate / chain certificate(s). That might be the reason stuff breaks.

Consider using the "fullchain" certificate bundle in your [`SSLcerificateFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) instead of only the server certificate in your Apache SSL config, or alternatively add a [`SSLCertificateChainFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) directive with the CA certificates that issued / signed your server certificate.